# Problema with the java build path with my private lib

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build, path

i have a doubt.
I import one proyect and there is an error.
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/NadirFagot/Desktop/Proyecto Fonta/Irlanda/supporting/GROUPEE/libs/._android-support-v4.jar' in project 'GROUPEE' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file  GROUPEE     Build path  Build Path Problem

When i go to the proyect properties and java build path and libraries, i try to remove in the android private libraries one of the files android-support-v4.jar, because there are two but i can't.
I tried to delete the hidden file jar in the window view in my folder libs and install it with the android tools but it doesn't work too.

I don't know what i have to do...
PLEASE HELP!!

THANKSS

Answer (score 0):

If your library projects contains android.v4 support jar you can remove from your project and clean the project..